# Diminuir quatidade de "if"

Tags: java, if

Olá !!
Fiz um código Java para responder um exercício e fiquei curioso para diminuir a quantidade de "if" a fim de melhorar o código,quem poder ajudar. 
O questionário pede.
Desenvolva um programa que leia quatro valores numéricos inteiros e mostre os valores que são divisíveis por 2 e 3.

```
public class ValorDivisivel{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.print("Digite 1° num: ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        System.out.print("Digite 2° num: ");
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        System.out.print("Digite 3° num: ");
        int num3 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        System.out.print("Digite 4° num: ");
        int num4 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());           

        System.out.print("Valor divisível por 2: ");
        if(num1 % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(num1+"  ");        
        }
        if(num2 % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(num2+"  ");        
        } 
        if(num3 % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(num3+"  ");        
        }
        if(num4 % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(num4+" ");     
        }
        if(num1 % 2 != 0 && num2 % 2 != 0 && num3 % 2 != 0 && num4 % 2 != 0){
            System.out.println("Não tem!!!");
        }
        System.out.print("Valor divisível por 3: ");
        if(num1 % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print(num1+"  ");        
        }
        if(num2 % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print(num2+"  ");        
        }
        if(num3 % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print(num3+"  ");        
        }
        if(num4 % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print(num4+" ");     
        }
        if(num1 % 3 != 0 && num2 % 3 != 0 && num3 % 3 != 0 && num4 % 3 != 0){
            System.out.println("Não tem!!!");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: Para mais detalhes: https://onlinegdb.com/Bkrfxo_qU

Comment: No YouTube tem ótimas explicações sobre esse assunto em português.